# Moto g unable to receive SMS after android 4.4.4

Tags: updates, motorola-moto-g, sms-blocking

Recently I updated my motog from android 4.4.3 to 4.4.4 through OTA after that I can able to send SMS but unable to receive any SMS. Before updating everything worked fine.
I don't know what happened I changed my default SMS app to hangout but no success, even I uninstalled the hangout updates and reinstalled still no success.

When I send SMS from another mobile its not received.

Please help me to get out of this.

Comment: Make sure the APN settings are still correct.  Settings -> More -> Mobile networks -> Access Point Names.  Check with your carrier for proper settings.

Comment: @Chahk Thanks for your reply. I just resolved by doing a factory reset. All other things didn't worked.

Comment: Don't forget to post this as an answer (yes, you can answer your own questions on this site) and accept it, so that others with similar problem may benefit from your research.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just resolved by doing a factory reset. All other things didn't worked